# Python Subprocess is not executing pipeline

Tags: python, windows, cmd, subprocess

I need to execute the following list of commands:

> gpg --card-edit
>
> admin
>
> name

however subprocess is stuck in some kind of while loop(?) when i execute the first command. it doesn't execute 'admin' and 'name' commands.

it shows console and i can write them manually but i want to do that automatically as there are more instructions later. how to do that automatically?

```
if sys.platform.startswith('win'):
    command = ['cmd', '/c', 'gpg', '--card-edit']
else:
    command = ['gpg', '--card-edit']
p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

print('hello!')

output = p.communicate(input='admin\n'.encode())[0]
print(output)
output = p.communicate(input='name\n'.encode())[0]
print(output)
```

i also wrote print('hello') for test if it executes and it doesn't. i wanted to try pexecute lib but it doesn't work well on Windows.

i've tried many options already including p.stdin.write and p.stdin.flush but it still didnt work. it just looks like it doesnt go next line after 'subprocess.Popen'

I've also tried something like this:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

p.stdin.write('admin\n'.encode()) 

p.stdin.flush() 

print(p.stdout.readline())
```

same situation :/

Comment: The problem is `communicate`. It is intended to be used for one single communication and blocks everything until the end. Do not use it and instead try to directly `read` and `write` to the subprocess input and output pipes.

Comment: i've already tried something like this:

```p.stdin.write("admin\n".encode())
p.stdin.flush()
output = p.stdout.read()```

and this;

```p.stdin.write('admin\n'.encode())
p.stdin.flush()
output, err = p.communicate()```

 but it still doesnt work

Comment: `p.stdout.read()` is also a blocking function until the process terminates, you probably want `readline` instead.

Comment: i think i've tried almost every option already and it still doesn't work;

```p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

p.stdin.write('admin\n'.encode())
p.stdin.flush()
print(p.stdout.readline())```

Comment: Maybe the program does not read from stdin and opens the terminal. Try the command in the terminal with an input redirection `.... </dev/null` (On Windows probably: `... <NUL`). Does it still accept keyboard input?

Comment: @VPfB you mean run the script and type 'admin <NULL' manually as it wasn't executed by script? it works the same as 'admin' manually

Comment: @park3r No, I mean `gpg --card-edit <NUL` to check if you can successfully enter `admin` + `name`. If yes, the `Popen` cannot work. If no, the issue must be elsewhere.

Comment: @VPfB
`command = ['cmd', '/c', 'gpg', '--card-edit', '<NULL']
p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
p.stdin.write('admin\n'.encode())
print(p.stdout.readline())
print(p)
`

gives:
`b''
<Popen: returncode: None args: ['cmd', '/c', 'gpg', '--card-edit', '<NULL']>
`

if i remove stdin write and readline then there is no b''

Comment: @park3r No, do not run the python script, run only the command. Manually, just once to test.

Comment: @VPfB 
so gpg --card-edit <NUL gives the same result as without it. same in script

Comment: @park3r Well, if the `gpg --card-edit` does not read from the stdin, you cannot send the input from a script using a pipe. I checked the man page and you probably need to add this option `--command-fd=0` to force it to read from the stdin.

Comment: @VPfB thanks that's what i was looking for! Can you post it as an answer so this thread can be closed :) ?